# How a passed variable to pug are accessible in pug script?

Tags: html, express, pug

I am now to web development, in fact, this is the first one I am working on. I am trying to pass a variable from my main app like

```
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    getdata().then(record=>{
        res.render("index",{title:'Login',users:record})
    })        
})
```

Then in my index.pug file the variable is accessible everywhere except my script there like

```
form()
          input(type="text", class='normal',id='uname', placeholder = 'Username')
          input(type="password", class='normal',id='password', placeholder='Password')
          input(type="submit", class='submit',value="Login",onclick="checkaccount(users)")
script.
    function checkaccount(users){
      let user=document.getElementById('uname').value
      let password = document.getElementById('password').value
      console.log(users)
    }
```

the code won't execute because users variable is not defined I guess.
**users variable is an array of array with format array(a,b)
this works when i use

```
each val in users
    p.
        val
```

elsewhere from my scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `script.` means that everything that follows is interpreted as literal. you can still use the code, but the syntax is different:

```
script.
    var users = JSON.parse('#{JSON.stringify(users)'});
    function checkaccount(/*set users elsewhere*/){
      let user=document.getElementById('uname').value
      let password = document.getElementById('password').value
      console.log(users)
    }
```

actually, this is not a good idea, better to use a serialization library, but the idea is that you have to serialize it, then tell put to get make a string literal `'#{}'` out of an expression `#{}` and then parse it on frontend (`JSON.parse('#{}')`). You would have to `JSON.stringify().replace(/'/g, "'")` to prevent the single quote in one of your data to break this solution.

on the frontend, with object `{'hello': "world's"}`:

```
- var myvalue = JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/'/g, "\\'");
JSON.parse('#{myvalue}')
```

becomes

```js
JSON.parse('{"hello":"world\'s"}');
```

Comment: This solution breaks down the whole structure. Everything stops working. the problem i think is that the users i am passing is not an object its an array. like [[a,b],[c,d],[e,f],...]

Comment: Ok i get it now. within my script i have to use it like `console.log('#{users}')` Thanks @Dave Ankin